# PHP - convert coordinates / position to standard latitude and longitude format

Tags: php, gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I've got coordinates like this: `48°22´5.901240 10°53´49.81379`

First I thought just remove all the crap like ° and then you get 48.225901 latitude and 10,53498 longitude, but no it's about 30 kilometers wrong and actually `48.3683059` latitude and `10.89717` longitude smh..

How do I convert the coordinates with all the °´ bs to the proper format?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+degrees+minutes+seconds+to+decimal+degrees&oq=convert+degrees+minutes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find functions to do that [here](http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_6.php)